# Wordpress error 404 en migración de Apache a Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, 404

Tengo una instalación de Wordpress funcionando correctamente en servidor Apache y queria migrar a un servidor NGINX en un VPS. He copiado todos los archivos, configurado la conexión MSQL, etc.. y todo parece funcionar bien excepto los artículos publicados, que todos dan error 404. La zona de administración funciona bien, sin problemas aparentes.

La configuración del servidor virtual es:

```
server {
if ($host = www.xxx.es) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name xxx.es www.xxx.es;
return 301 https://www.xxx.es$request_uri;}

server {
server_name  xxx.es www.xxx.es;
root /home/www/xxx.es/html/;
index index.php;

#listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxx.es/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxx.es/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {return 404;}


fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Prueba a acceder al `wp-admin`
2. vete al apartado de estructura de permalinks en ajustes
3. vuelve a guardar aún sin hacer cambios.